# Can a class method local variable modify the class variable?

Tags: python

I have a class 'RAR' with atribute 'limit' (vector of size 'limit') and parent1' (vector of size 'size'). The limit vector is composed by integers from 1 to 31: [1,2,3...,31]. And the parent1 is composed by random 5 numbers in limit: [1,4,7,10,30] or [1,2,4,6,23]. I'm trying to create a method that will pick the class parent, and modify it changing one random element in parent1 by another element of limit not yet included in parent1. This method I've done is working, but it is modifying the original parent, what can't occur, the parent1 needs to be preserved. I've done it like a class method so I don't need to give the limit vector every time I call the method, since it is a class immutable vector. Why is the code modifying the original parent, since it is given as a local variable to the method? How can I fix this?

```
class RAR:
     def __init__(self,parent1,limit):
        self.parent1=#given vector parent1
        self.limit=[i for i in range(1,limit+1)]

     def mutation(self,parent):        #this functions perform a mutation in a given parent, changing one of the stocks for another asset not included
        cparent=parent #i tried this to see if creating another variable it wouldn't modigy the self.parent1
        k=rand.randint(0,len(parent)-1)
        a=parent.pop(k)
        b=rand.randint(0,len(limit)-1)
        while c!=1: 
            if check(b,cparent)==0 and b!=limit[a-1]:
                print("Executed if.")
                b=rand.randint(0,len(limit)-1)
                c=1
        print("For conference, a: "+str(a))
        print("Sorted number: "+str(b))
        cparent.append(b+1)
        cparent=bubble(parent)
        return parent
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre]. I posted a likely solution but I'm not able to confirm without an MRE. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this in the next asks, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, it's that lists are mutable and you're mutating it. Simply make a copy in the function:

```
def mutation(self, parent):
    cparent = parent.copy()  # <- here
    k = rand.randint(0, len(cparent)-1)
    a = cparent.pop(k)
    ...  # etc.
```